# 16.10 - no mouse, keyboard after boot but works after sleep/wake up

Tags: boot, dual-boot, keyboard, mouse

I have a Toshiba Satellite c670/670d laptopn. Last week I installed Ubuntu 16.10 next to Windows 7. As I can remember first it worked well (it's possible that's not, can't remember for sure), but then I discovered that after boot the mouse and keyboard are not working (before that there is no problem when I have to choose what OS to load). The USB mouse still works fine.

I have found similar questions but none of the answers from there solved my problem.

But accidentally I found out that if I close the laptop to go to sleep after login screen comes up, then I wait a few seconds and open it to wake than mouse and keyboard are working again.

I tried to check for errors after boot but nothing then I checked the syslog but since I'm not an expert in Linux I couldn't find any line with an important information for me.

I hope that with the sleep/wake information there is someone who got an idea how to solve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so here is another question ( https://askubuntu.com/a/348171/651062 ) what I didn't found until yesterday after I posted my question. There is an accepted answer which also solved my problem.

I copy that answer and accept it because it looks like it's still relevant.

> 1) Run the following command in terminal
>
> **sudo nano /etc/default/grub**
>
> 2) Locate the following section in the file:
>
> **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=" "**
>
> Replace it with:
>
> **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.nomux=1 i8042.reset"**
>
> 3) Save the file and exit nano.
>
> 4) Run the following command in terminal:
>
> **sudo update-grub**
>
> 5) Restart your computer.
>
> Now everything should work fine.